# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'Cache' on 'addAll': Request failed on progressive web app

Tags: web, service-worker

I am following a simple PWA tutorial, but when I complete it I get the following console error,

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'Cache' on 'addAll': Request failed`

Here is my serviceworker file

```
const staticDevCoffee = "dev-coffee-site-v1"
const assets = [
  "/",
  "/test.html",
  "/csstest/style.css",
  "/jstest/app.js",
  "/coffee.png",
]

self.addEventListener("install", installEvent => {
  installEvent.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticDevCoffee).then(cache => {
      cache.addAll(assets)
    })
  )
})
```

When I run lighthouse tests, I get this,

```
start_url does not respond with a 200 when offlineThe start_url did respond, but not via a service worker.
```

This is my first look at PWAs so I am a little stuck. I have tried several solutions I have found on SO, but none work.

Comment: Had this exact same error and glad it was already answered.  Led me to a .icns file that wasn't being served properly (due to mime type not set) and which failed and caused ServcieWorker to fail.  Thanks

Comment: I also had this problem. No problem on a Windows pc and android phone, but on an Ipad the service worker was not working. The problem was an image i removed, but was still in the pre-cache list.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

- For the first exception:-

  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'Cache' on 'addAll': Request failed

You get this exception when any files which you have mentioned in your cache list return a 404 response. So make sure the all the resources are giving 200.

- For the 2nd error:-

  start_url does not respond with a 200 when offlineThe start_url did respond.

In your case as files are not getting cached(due to first exception) you are getting this error and also make sure to cache root index file in your cache list.

Comment: And what happens when you've confirmed all assets are returning 200 and still you get this error?

Comment: @Vincent can you share your complete use case and code?

Answer (score 3):

I had also issues with this: In my app I have tens of files in the `assets[]` array to load into cache, manually picked (i.e. it doesn't make sense to cache `loading.gif` since it is not needed after the loading). Then any forgotten change makes the cache empty and the cause of the error is hidden, as the accepted answer explains. After I repeatedly spent time searching what was missing, I lost my patience with "convenient" `cache.addAll` and switched back to `cache.add`, so instead of the useless `TypeError` I get reported the file which caused the failure:

```
...
const filesUpdate = cache => {
    const stack = [];
    assets.forEach(file => stack.push(
        cache.add(file).catch(_=>console.error(`can't load ${file} to cache`))
    ));
    return Promise.all(stack);
};

installEvent.waitUntil(caches.open(staticDevCoffee).then(filesUpdate));
...
```

I hope this saves somebody nerves with `cache.addAll()`, too.

Answer (score 3):

Typos in the file list can be a common cause for failure (404). `cache.addAll()` fails the entire batch without providing any guidance on what exactly failed. Upon failure, the code below adds each file individually with `cache.add()` and logs which file failed.

Notes:

- `addAll()` and `add()` are both promises, and `async/await` works well
- Both return `undefined` on `resolve()`
- `addAll()` error in `try/catch` is a very vague/unhelpful `TypeError: Failed to execute 'addAll' on 'Cache': Request failed`, which is why `err` is not output to `console.error()`
- `add()` doesn't even provide an error, thus the far more useful loop item (filpath) in the `console.warn()`

  ```
  //code
  self.addEventListener('install', e => {
    e.waitUntil(caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(async (cache) => {
      let ok,
      cats = [
        'a', 'folder', 'with',
        'lots', 'of', 'files',
        'for', 'the', 'same', 'extension'
      ],
      c = [
        '/css/video-js.css',
        '/img/base/favicon.ico',
        '/img/base/favicon.png',
        '/img/base/favicon.svg',
        ...cats.map(i => '/img/cat/' + i + '.jpg'),
        '/img/svg/404.svg',
        '/js/caman.full.min.js',
        '/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js',
        '/js/video.min.js'
        ];

      console.log('ServiceWorker: Caching files:', c.length, c);
      try {
        ok = await cache.addAll(c);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('sw: cache.addAll');
        for (let i of c) {
          try {
            ok = await cache.add(i);
          } catch (err) {
            console.warn('sw: cache.add',i);
          }
        }
      }

      return ok;
    }));

    console.log('ServiceWorker installed');
  });
  ```

With typos, the console output looks something like:

> ServiceWorker installed
>
> ServiceWorker: Caching files: 77
>
> ServiceWorker registered: https://local.dev/
>
> sw: cache.addAll
>
> sw: cache.add /img/cat/booking.jpg
>
> sw: cache.add /img/cat/prc.jpg
>
> ServiceWorker activated

Fixed the typos (booking -> bookings, prc -> pr), unregistered the sw, reloaded the page. Log without typos:

> ServiceWorker installed
>
> ServiceWorker: Caching files: 77
>
> ServiceWorker registered: https://local.dev/
>
> ServiceWorker activated

Damm these fat fingers...

Answer (score 0):

```
self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
    console.log("Service Worker : Installed!")

    event.waitUntil(
        
        (async() => {
            try {
                cache_obj = await caches.open(cache)
                cache_obj.addAll(caching_files)
            }
            catch{
                console.log("error occured while caching...")
            }
        })()
    )
} )
```

This code worked for me!

Comment: This does not address the issue and instead simply ignores it. Your service worker will be installed but your cache will not work as expected with this code. The accepted answer is the correct way to handle this issue. If you are having issues that the solution above does not resolve, you should ask your own question.

Comment: Worked fine for me https://github.com/shilu10/Service-Worker