# django PWA serviceworker Failed to execute 'addAll' on 'Cache': Request failed

Tags: python, django, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, browser-cache

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'addAll' on 'Cache': Request failed 
serviceworker.js:1
```

Above is the error from my dev tools console upon launching a django progressive web app. Below is my full **serviceworker.js** file

```
    var staticCacheName = 'djangopwa-v1';

    self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(staticCacheName).then(function(cache) {
        return cache.addAll([
            '/index',
        ]);
        })
    );
    });
    
    self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    var requestUrl = new URL(event.request.url);
        if (requestUrl.origin === location.origin) {
        if ((requestUrl.pathname === '/')) {
            event.respondWith(caches.match('/index'));
            return;
        }
        }
        event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
        );
    });
```

I tried keeping cache.addAll empty but I still get the same error. I have not put in any offline support because I do not intend to use the app offline. I want to fix this but these posts were not helpful [Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'Cache' on 'addAll': Request failed on progressive web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66529102/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-failed-to-execute-cache-on-addall-request) and [Django - ServiceWorker, Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'addAll' on 'Cache': Request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69820286/django-serviceworker-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-failed-to-execute-adda)

I got the **serviceworker.js** from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/make-pwa-of-a-django-project/ and it throws the same error.

Comment: can your provide your directory structure

Comment: I have the same error